# Location Background Mode Always or WhenInUse

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have two apps built that use your location similar to a run tracking app where I use the location in the background but only when you are actively tracking a run. This works in iOS 11 after only requesting WhenInUse authorization and you get the top blue bar when you leave the app. Both are in the app store but in my most recent submission I keep getting rejected with the following response:

> Regarding 5.1.5, the current modal alert available to the user requests permission to access the Foreground Location. However, your app does not request and obtain the user's consent prior to accessing their background location data, which is not allowed on the App Store.

Is this something new and they just haven't noticed before? I also checked Google Maps and Strava and they both use my location when I'm actively using it even when they are in WhenInUse mode.

I would prefer to use only WhenInUse mode as I think it more clearly conveys to the user what the app is doing. We never use your location when the app isn't recording a run.

If you can link to Apple documentation about this situation it would help even more.

Comment: How can you possibly use location data in the background if you only were granted when in use permission?  IOS should not deliver location updates in this case.

Comment: Its always worked this way as far as I can tell. I believe it is intended behavior after checking other apps. You just need to set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates and it only works with the blue bar until you close the app. It doesn't allow you to launch and app into the background.

Comment: @Jeremiah I agree that the when in use behaviour makes more sense for your scenario. Waze also displays the blue bar. Have you appealed to Apple?

Comment: I have with no luck. I should probably have formulated my case better. Partly why i’m looking for documentation. I’ve resubmitted in hopes of a different reviewer.